# Use a DNS server for a particular domain when on VPN

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn, dnsmasq

I want to use a particular domain name server for a given domain only when connected to the VPN. The rest of the lookups should be resolved by another domain name server, including that same domain if not connected to the VPN.

That is, if connected to the VPN and looking up somedomain.com, the DNS server on the VPN's network should resolve the query. Any other will be resolved by my ISP's DNS server. If disconnected from the VPN, all queries should be resolved by my ISP's DNS server, including somedomain.com.

I have been looking at Split DNS, and other options. Tried with dnsmasq but apparently Network Manager already uses it and I get a conflict when trying to bring up the service.

I tried by specifying an additional domain search and DNS server in the Network Manager UI for the OpenVPN connection. This solves the problem as long as there is no overlap. But for domain names that can be resolved with the same name both locally (under the VPN network) and publicly, it still uses the public route while on the VPN.

Thanks in advance. Kind of new to network management.

Comment: Are you certain that the external DNS is resolving your query? Have you tried querying with the fully qualified domain name? In the default installation of an OpenVPN connection you should get a `tap` or `tun` interface (check with `ip addr`), and this should normally take precedence (as specified in `/etc/resolvconf/interface-order`) over other network interfaces w.r.t. DNS resolution. If this is not the case, I would consider filing a bug against `resolvconf`, `network-manager`, or `systemd` (with all the changes in the past years I'm not sure which tree to bark up to).

Comment: Yes @zwets, it would take precedence, but I am ignoring the routes pushed to me by the VPN server and only using it for its subnet. I don't want to use the DNS server on that subnet unless I am looking for anything under somedomain.com.

Comment: Note there is the package `openvpn-systemd-resolved` which supposedly integrates OpenVPN with systemd-resolved. You could try if it helps.